# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, configuration

I have problem with my Dynamic Web Application. I just started learning JavaEE 6 and now I stack on JPA. I configured my app, added libraries but I still get this annoying info: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X. I try to get answer in Internet, but nothing help me.

This is my persistance.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PierwszaAplikacja" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>devcastzone.javaee.Uzytkownik</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/szkolenie_javaee?characterEncoding=utf8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my class Uzytkownik.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="uzytkownik")
public class Uzytkownik implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3299291830280417103L;
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And my EntityManagerFactory creator in servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    res.setContentType("text/plain;charset=utf-8");
    res.getWriter().println("Cos tam cos tam");
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PierwszaAplikacja");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Uzytkownik u = em.find(Uzytkownik.class, 1);
    res.getWriter().println(u.getImie() + " " + u.getNazwisko() + "\n");
    em.close();
    emf.close();
    }
```

Of course I have my persistence.xml in root in META-INF. Maybe anyone can help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I had the same problem this week.

Try to **copy META-INF into java src.** (same place as your packages)

It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WAR file for deploying the application, then the persistence.xml file should be located under **WEB-INF/classes/META-INF** directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change the provider from:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

to:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```